# How to sync 3 values using laravel sync() in many to many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, laravel-controller

I need to sync 3 values in a table in which, I have 3 fields in a table as `difficulty_level_id`, `sbj_type_id` and `subject_id` and I have setup this thing in my Controller as:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $difficulty_level = DifficultyLevel::find(1);
    $difficulty_level->sbj_types()->sync($request->veryeasy, false);
    return 'done';
}
```

but the problem is that it only attaches 2 values as `difficulty_level_id` and `sbj_type_id`. How I sync the third values as `subject_id`, any help will be appreciated?

Comment: That's not what `sync()` is meant for though, right? From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships): *You may also use the sync method to construct many-to-many associations. The sync method accepts an array of IDs to place on the intermediate table. Any IDs that are not in the given array will be removed from the intermediate table.*

Comment: So is there any other way to do this?